# Error when opening a table through the admin panel of a Django site

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, sqlite

Into the Django project imported a SQLite database containing records. When opening tables containing fields with the Date type through the admin panel, an error occurs (see below); when opening other tables of this database, no errors occur.
ERROR

```
return datetime.date(*map(int, val.split(b"-")))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'19 00:00:00'
```

models.py file

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    registry_number = models.TextField(primary_key=True, blank=True, null=False)
    link_to_contract = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_conclusion_of_a_contract = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Contract'
```

[image: BD]

Comment: It already mentioned in the error `19 00:00:00`  your split won't work for that part of the string

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna Data in a DB row is stored in the format (Y-m-d h: m: s). The division by "-" is chosen by the program itself. There are 400,000 records in the database. What can be done in such cases?

Comment: Using pandas `pd.to_datetime(df['Invoice Date'], format='%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` I didn't test it ... might work %y %m.... are strftime directives